# How to selectively do summation of Template and Image Patch pixels based on the corresponding alpha channel pixel in Template?

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, computer-vision

I am using this OpenCV function ([cv2.matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#cv2.matchTemplate)) in Python.

There are 6 matching methods that I can use. The following are 2 examples.

*CV_TM_SQDIFF:*

[image]

*CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED:*

[image]

According to the documentation, the summation is done over *all pixels* in the Template Image and Image Patch from source image.

In my template image, I have a alpha channel which consists of `0 (fully transparent)` and `1 (fully opaque)` only.

When I use the `cv2.matchTemplate` function, I want to ignore the pixels with `0 (fully transparent)`. In other words, for pixels with `0 (fully transparent)`, I want to treat it as a Full Match between Template and Image Patch. For pixels with `1 (fully opaque)`, I want to do normal summation.

For *CV_TM_SQDIFF* and *CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED* methods, I think a full match means the `T (template)` and `I (Image Patch)` will sum to zero (for a particular pixel). I am not sure about other methods.

So, my `R` summation for a particular (x, y) will become something like this:

```
R = (normal summation) + .. + 0 + 0 + .. + (normal summation) + 0 + ..
                              |   |                             |
        [These pixels have a alpha channel = 0, the other pixels are 1]
```

I have found the [source codes of `cv2.matchTemplate` function](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ea1b14ee95e0d5412ab4c98d8a4886555b25331c/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp) which is written in C++.

1. The `cv2.matchTemplate` function is at line 828.
2. The `ocl_matchTemplate` function is at line 549.
3. The `matchTemplate_SQDIFF` function is at line 377.
4. The `matchTemplate_SQDIFF_NORMED` function is at line 412.

I am new in C++ programming. I have read the source codes for a very long time but still not very clear at which line I should add the codes to do selective summation of `T` and `I` based on the corresponding alpha channel pixel.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/5639/matchtemplate-with-a-mask/

Comment: @AdiShavit Thanks. Although I haven't tested the code yet, but it seems that the solution given by `germano2239` in that post is able to solve my problem. Please put your answer in the answer section. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5639/matchtemplate-with-a-mask/). One of the answers might give you your solution.